# What is this (house)plant? (Stiff Red central spike with white tips; possibly a Bromeliad?)

Tags: identification

Click for full size:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I got this plan indirectly from a relative who passed away ... so I don't know *anything* about its origin.

The green leaves are very stiff and waxy.
The colourful spike in the centre doesn't have the texture of flower petals - the red/white bits are stiff, hard and strong: with care, I can lift the entire plant whilst holding two of them.

Some very crude googling suggests that it *might* be a Bromeliad? Though it's set in a soil-filled pot, which isn't the impression I get of Bromeliads.

Comment: A bromeliad but i don't know which one. The plant that bloomed will die and new ones will start at the base, very likely. They can use a little water in the center.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Ah, so the colourful section _is_ a flower, then? Cool :)

Comment: Yes , the flowers last for months.